# How make delete option appear when hover the image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, codeigniter-3

I want to make the delete option appear when the image is hover.i dont know how to do it.so guys please help me?my view is like this:

```
<?php include('inc/header.php');?>

    <div class="main">



        <?php
            foreach ($view as $row) {
                echo "<div class='grow'>";
                echo "<img src='".base_url()."images/".$row->image."' >";
                echo "</div>";  
                }//end for each

        ?>




    </div>
<?php include('inc/footer.php');?>
```

My image already hovers but dont know how to embed the delete option within the image.

Comment: what delete option?

Comment: current hovered delete option..

Comment: oh, the current hovered delete option which appears when the image is hovered .... nope, not helping

Comment: The answer might work, consider putting the given html in the question only. This will make it easier for everyone looking at you question.

Comment: I have the list of the image which are retrieve from the database and i displayed them.But what if i want to delete those the specific image.so i like to have the delete option appear when i hover a specific image and when clicking that i can delete that image.@JaromandaX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a delete div -

```
<?php include('inc/header.php');?>

        <div class="main">



            <?php
                foreach ($view as $row) {
                    echo "<div class='grow'>";
                    echo "<div class='delete'><a href='#'>delete</a></div>";
                    echo "<img src='".base_url()."images/".$row->image."' >";
                    echo "</div>";  
                    }//end for each

            ?>




        </div>
    <?php include('inc/footer.php');?>
```

Then in script write a code to show/hide delete div -

```
$('.grow').hover(function () {
                      $(this).find('.delete').show();
                   }, 

                   function () {
                      $(this).find('.delete').hide();
                   })
```

Comment: Thanks but can the delete option appear with in the picture?@Rohan Veer

Comment: Write css for that -
.grow{
 position: relative;
}
.delete{
 position: absolute;
 top: 45%;
 right: 45%;
}